# Where to place the docblock annotations in Doctrine 2.3.3

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

I am upgrading my ORM from `Doctrine 1.2` to `Doctrine 2.3.3`. In the previous version we used to generate models and use them to interact with specific tables. But in the latter versions we write the docblock annotations.

I have written a docblock annotation that corresponds to my table in database and placing it inside `Doctrine\Common\Annotations`. But it seems that isnt working as the object of the annotation class is not getting recognized.

So where do i place the docblock files or what extra i do have to take for my doctrine to run properly?

Comment: 1) This question means nothing without examples. 2) Why are you making new annotation files? You're intended to annotate your models with the _existing_ annotations.

Comment: yea.. but the folder structure given by the Composer and the one shown in the documentation seems totally different.. struggling to proceed further..

Comment: Folder structure doesn't matter. Composer handles class autoloading for you. If composer is managing your dependencies, then all you need to do is add an annotation such as `@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column()` to a property in your class to add an annotation. (I could be wrong on the namespace but the point is the same).

Comment: yea.. got that.. now its up and running :) but can u pls tell me the way top write getters for date datatype??

Comment: Getters don't have anything specific related to datatype. Only setters do (if you want type hinting). A getter should just be: `public function getDateCreated() { return $this->dateCreated; }`

Comment: yea but it gives an error saying UnitOfWork cannot convert date to string type.. so i m guessing there shud be a return type specified as when we specify the datatype while setting the data..

Comment: That's not how PHP works. There are no return data types in PHP. If Doctrine is complaining about not being able to convert, then you have the mapping of your field wrong. In your `Column` annotation, did you specify `type="datetime"`? The full definition should look something like: `@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")`

Comment: yea.. actually i hav the idea abt return types.. and u were correct.. there was a slight mistake in the mapping.. and its been solved.. thanks a lot for ur help.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter where you place your annotations, Doctrine is not programmed to recognise them. It only knows how to deal with its own annotations.